# NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey: cannot decode object of class for key (NS.objects)

Tags: swift, codable, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I looked through whole SO but still no answer. My app reports this problem:

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException
>   *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (App_Title.Products) for key (NS.objects); the
>   class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked

I did already do NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass just before #unarchiveObject:

```
func loadProducts() -> [Products]? {
    NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Products.self, forClassName: "Products")
    let unarchivedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Products.ArchiveURL.path)
```

My Products class begins with @Objc:

```
import Foundation

@objc(Products)
class Products: NSObject, Codable, NSCoding { ... }
```

Adding the two lines above which seemed to help people didn't bring me any luck. Before them and after them it's the same behaviour. I personally could never reproduce this issue myself.

During development I keep very closely to the app guide on [peristance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html) and reviewed it multiple times.

Just before NSKeyedArchiver I check for file existance:

```
let filePath = Products.ArchiveURL.path
let fileManager = FileManager.default
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
```

Here some additional informations in screenshots.

The only place where I could find a real exception description was Firebase Crashalytics:

[image]

A screenshot from the Xcode Organizer under the Crash tab:

[image]

Which leads to this line in the code:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Products.self, forClassName: "Products")
let unarchivedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Products.ArchiveURL.path)
```

[image]

Products class with @Objc annotation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing up `Codable` and `NSCoding`. Don't try to use both simultaneously. `NSKeyedUnarchiver` belongs to `NSCoding`.

Your class contains property list compliant properties. Drop `NSCoding` and use only `Codable`. (By the way it's recommended to name the class in singular form `Product`).

Delete everything which is related to `NSCoding` including the protocol conformance and with `Codable` it's not necessary that the class must inherit from `NSObject` (the object can be even a struct).

The `loadProducts` function can be reduced to

```
func loadProducts() throws -> [Product] {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: Product.ArchiveURL)
    return try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
}
```

It's good practice to hand over `thrown` errors to the caller

And delete the `CodingKeys`, you don't need them if the keys match the property names.

Comment: Yes yes yes. That is the answer! Wonderful solution @vadian. For encoding I use PropertyListEncoder and implemented a recovery process for my old NSKeyedUnarchiver objects.